# Promise.all not waiting for promises to finish before moving to .then

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to preform two gets in reactjs then process the result for display.

I've set both my fetches as promises to be resolved. When I do promise.all however it moves onto the .then BEFORE the fetches have completed. Here is the code below.

```
 const getC = fetch(api/getContacts, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
           'Authorization': JSON.stringify(this.props.getLogin()),
           'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
     })
     .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.status);
        res.json()
        .then(json => {
           json = json.sort(this.sortByProperty('contact_id'));
           console.log(json)
           this.setState({
              contactsLoading: false,
              contacts: json
           });
        })
     });
 const getG = fetch(api/getContacts, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
           'Authorization': JSON.stringify(this.props.getLogin()),
           'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({group_id: this.props.group_id
        })
     })
     .then((res) => {
        res.json()
        .then(json => {
           console.log(json);
           var members = json.members.sort(this.sortByProperty('contact_id'));
           console.log(members);
           this.setState({
              name: json.name,
              memberIds: members,
           });
        })
     });
Promise.all([getG, getC])
     .then(() => {
        console.log(this.state.contacts);
        console.log(this.state.memberIds);
     });
```

The expected output is:
[Array with items] (from getG)
[Array with items] (from getC)
[same array as get C] (in the .then)
[same array as get G]

but instead I'm getting:
[empty array]
[empty array] (from the .then)

[Array from getG]
[Array from getC]

So I'm trying to figure out why Promise.all isn't await the fetches to finish before moving on, its completely perplexing.

Comment: `return  res.json()
        .then(json => {` , you forgot the return statement to nested promise is not chained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getC` and `getG` promises aren't actually waiting for their actions to complete.

You need to `return` the inner promise chain in `res.json().then(...)` from the outer `then()` callback to make the outer promise wait for that chain.

Once you're doing that, you should also move the inner `then()` callback up to reduce nesting:

```
 const getC = fetch(api/getContacts, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
           'Authorization': JSON.stringify(this.props.getLogin()),
           'Accept': 'application/json',
           'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
     })
     .then((res) => {
        console.log(res.status);
        return res.json()
     })
     .then(json => {
        ...
     });
```

Comment: Thank you! I realized this after I posted the question, but I didn't realize you could return res.json(). Still new to this.